# Area of a Shape

Tags: area

A cathedral window is built in the shape of a semicircle.  If the window is to contain three stained glass sections of equal size, what is the area of each stained glass section?  Express answer to the nearest square foot.

Comment: Do you know anything else about this semicircle?

Comment: No, that was all that was given in the problem.

Comment: There is obviously something missing. Is this window the size of peanut or the size of an elephant? By "size", do you mean "area"?

Comment: @MPW Yes, they would mean area. It would simply depend on radius.

Comment: From what I understand, they all have the same area.

Comment: Even if you have more information you are likely to have to ignore the area of the structures which separate the sections.

Comment: @IHeartBunnies check my hint, you would want to solve in terms of r, if it doesn't give you a picture/more info.

Comment: @MarkBennet This seems like an ideal question, so I would assume the separator is infinitly thin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The area of a circle is $A= \pi r^2$, then what is the area of a semi-circle? What if you divide that in three parts?

**Edit:** If it is asking without more context, I suspect it wants area in terms of $r$?

Answer (score 2):

Area of a circle is $\pi r^2$, since we are talking about a semicircle, this is just 
$$\frac {\pi r^2}{2}$$

Since this semicircle is further divided into 3 sections, divide the area of the semicircle into 3, thus

$$\frac {\pi r^2}{6}$$

Comment: You've given the only possible answer, given the incomplete  nature of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The question could have been more interesting if the width of each shutter in the semicircular arch was to be determined. The areas of the three shutters are assumed to be equal. and the shutters have perfectly vertical frames of negligible thickness.